# C# - How does a for loop understand the following syntax and why it works?

Tags: c#, loops, syntax

## [DOTNET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Cdmye)

So, I left the for loop totally empty and did the following:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 0;
        for(;;){
            if(i < 5){
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I knew that it would work, but I don't know how why it works. Could someone explain to me why this works and how the for loop understands that syntax?

I'm new to C# so take it easy on me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for

Comment: This is a _for_ syntax that has no initialization, no exit condition and no increment. All these parts are optional by language specs. The compiler should understand it and it creates an infinite loop, unless code meets a break statement

Comment: `for(;;)` is a simple *infinite loop*: initialize nothing, check (for exit) nothing, update (increment) nothing; `while (true)` is an alternative syntax

Comment: But how does the loop understands that the initialization is referring to `int i = 0`? I could put any variable there and as many variables as I want to.

Comment: *"But how does the loop understands"* - loop does not understand anything. Loop is a command - repeat this over. The condition in the loop is `for( ; while; )`. In this loop, this condition is missing and control over number of iterations is coded into the loop. Where you declare your index valriable (`i`) and where you increment it is not important. You can do `int i = 0; while (i < 10) { i++;}`. This is not any different than `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for(...)` loop with no initialization, condition, iteration step `for(;;)` is an *Infinite Loop* which runs forever unless an explicit exit condition given

Comment: Oh! It's an infinite loop because there is nothing there, but it iterates throught the `int i = 0` and increments that variable, once it reaches 4, the expression in the `else` clause is evaluated, then it breaks the infinite loop. Is that right?

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida yes. it has nothing to do with the for loop knowing about the i. it does not know about the i. the body of the for loop is doing that with the if() and the i++.

Comment: Could you add that comment to your answer? Programming languages are crazy stuff. I use them, but I don't know the theory behind them. That's trouble.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between `for(;;)` and `while(true)`. You can use whatever you like.

Comment: I know that. I know that for(;;) is an infinite loop, but I don't know how the initialization, once empty, now understands that I'm referring to `int i = 0`

Comment: Well, in the code sample you have provided `int i = 0;` is a variable declaration outside of the loop so you can access it from the inner scope.

Answer (score 2):

Each part of a for loop (;;) contains a statement. As you know first section for initialization then condition checking and finally the increment/decrement section.

If you leave them empty then the loop will iterate for infinite times like it happens for while(true).